# qml - Flickable vertical scroll by mouse wheel not work with WebEngineView

Tags: qt, qml

When I try to use the custom scrollbar in WebEngineView, I found it couldn't scroll by mouse wheel.

Simple code:

```
Flickable {
...
boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
WebEngineView{
    ...
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why?

---

Reference this [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43602),WebEngineView maybe cannot receive some events because of OpenGL.

But I find a simulated scrolling method by MouseArea:

```
Flickable {
...
boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{
    id:scroller
}

WebEngineView{
    ...
  }
}

MouseArea{
......
onWheel: {
    if(wheel.angleDelta.y > 0){
      scroller.decrease()
    }else{
      scroller.increase()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code won't run.

Comment: @Mitch emmm..... There is a sample [code](https://github.com/CrazyCxl/markdown-editor) here.